# PowerPoint 2010 won't open downloaded files

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

Whenever I download a file from the Internet and try to open in in PowerPoint 2010, it fails with a message

> PowerPoint found a problem with the content in . PowerPoint can
>   attempt to repair the presentation. If you trust the source of this
>   presentation, click Repair.

Clicking Repair never works. I have to close PowerPoint, right-click the file and go to Properties, then click a button that appears called "Unblock", then the file will open fine.

I'm tired of having to use this workaround. In Word 2010 and Excel 2010, files from the Internet open fine, and they just display a yellow warning bar at the top of the window ("Protected View") and prevent editing until I click a button to accept the risk.

Is there a fix that will make PowerPoint 2010 behave like Word and Excel?

Comment: Protected view as default is a security feature so I'd imagine there's some setting buried somewhere that allows for this.

Comment: We had this problem and it was related to the Trust Centre settings regarding "Protected View" - see answer http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/cannot-open-downloaded-powerpoint-files-in/21765edf-d5b4-4256-a23a-e8e8282cc466 to change the view settings.

Comment: The warning is due to Zone information added to the [ADS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29) of downloaded files. This doesn't answer your question, but as a *last resort* the warning can be turned off completely using [Group Policy](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/182353-open-file-security-warning-enable-disable.html), or you can use MS/SysInternals' [Streams](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx) to delete the file's ADS. Do *not* do this if you're unsure about the consequences however, since it weakens security.

Answer (score 1):

Answer on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.powerpoint/vsH6MTjZusk

Click File, 
Click options,
Click Trust Centre,
Click Trust Center Settings,
Click Protected View,
Untick enable protected view from files originating from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this question and I'm searching for the answer. 
But if you are in an emergency, you can download it in another device such as phone or tablet, then move it to your computer using a flash.

Comment: This does not remove the trusted source issue at the root of OP.

Answer (score -1):

Most of this nonsense can be quelled if you:

Right-click the icon of the downloaded file
Click Properties
Click UNBLOCK at the bottom of the dialog that appears.

If there's no UNBLOCK option, then it's a different problem.

Comment: I mentioned this workaround in my question. I'd like to find a way to fix the problem, not mask it.

Comment: So you did; my bad.  Have you tried the suggestion from John Wilson in the thread @Big Chris linked to?